# Video stretch issue iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video

I have an application with Swift. I want to play some video by using moviePlayer. I am using the following code.

```
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
//        moviePlayer?.controlStyle = .None
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 165, width: widthVideoView, height: heightVideoView)
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)

        }
```

Playing video is fine no issues. But for now my video is stretched . I think this is happening because of

```
        player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
```

My screenshot like this. [image].

So I change to

```
player.scalingMode = .AspectFit
```

Then my screen like this (top bottom with black screen.) How can I handle this.[image]

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Look at my first screenshot video stretched right? In my second there is black space. I want video in full size like first and without stretch.

Comment: try this player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthVideoView, height: heightVideoView) and layer.scalingMode = .AspectFit

Comment: I need x and y position must not 0. And read my question I already tried layer.scalingMode = .AspectFit

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the edited answer , If you read the docu : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieScalingMode

- .aspectFit: will create the blackBar because it keeps the aspect ratio of the video
- .aspectFill , will act like a zoom on the (there is no black bar but the video get cut)

  - .Fill will stretch the video to fit (I think you want this one or change the view to follow the aspect ratio ).

If you don't respect the original aspect ratio :It will always stretch or have  the black bars too fill .
So you can change the scalingMode to .Fill or change the view to respect the aspect ratio

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: more info on aspect ratio and current video standard : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)#Current_video_standards

Comment: I didn't tested it but this one seems promising to get the aspect ratio of a video https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2794706?start=0&tstart=0